# Problems getting fragment world position

Tags: opengl, glsl

I´m trying to get the fragment world position in the shader. For this, I create a fbo, bind  a texture to it with format GL_RGB32F and attach it to the GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1,&fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,fbo);

glGenTextures(1,&texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGB32F,WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT,0,GL_RGB,GL_FLOAT,NULL);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture,0);
```

The vertex and fragment shader looks as follows:

Vertex Shader

```
#version 330
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexposition;

out vec4 position; 

uniform mat4 MVP;
uniform mat4 Model;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = MVP*vec4(vertexposition,1.0f);
    position = Model*vec4(vertexposition,1.0f);
}
```

Fragment Shader

```
#version 330
in vec4 position;

out vec3 outputPosition;

void main()
{
    outputPosition = position.xyz;
}
```

If I´m right, outputPosition has the fragment position in world coordinates, due to the interpolation of the vertices world positions.

After the call to glDrawArrays, I read the color buffer, having this fragment world positions:

```
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
glReadPixels(0,0,WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT,GL_RGB,GL_FLOAT,pixelInfo);
```

But when I draw these points they doesn´t match the position of my object. I can´t find where is the error. Any idea?

Comment: Can you show how you are constructing the model-view matrix (i.e. the `Model` uniform)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve solved the probem using a depth buffer. The error was in the way that I recognized the pixels that were drawn.